# Nested tables using display:table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want to achieve the effect of nested tables using the `display:table`, `display:table-row`, `display:table -cell`.

The effect is such that nested table has a width equal to first cell of the main table.

See demo:https://jsfiddle.net/bu9mnegr/1/

I remember that in table is attribute colspan and nested table has width of all cells of main table. How can I do it without colspan?

Comment: i think you need border:1px solid #000; for classes.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bu9mnegr/2/

Comment: yeah, it's better to see where is my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/bu9mnegr/4/

Answer (score 0):

try this:
note the "with" should be 100% for each "table-col" to span...

```
<div class="display-table">
    <div>
        <div>cell</div>
        <div>cell</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div style="display:block; width:200%;">
            <div class="display-nested-table">
                <div>
                    <div>nested cell</div>
                    <div>nested cell</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works fine if cells in the main table have equal width (for example 50%), but if there are more cells with diffrent widths(40% - 30% - 30%) then 200% is the 200% of width first cell, in this case 80% width of main table.

Comment: "colspan" cannot be done when using "display" is a limitation. The only solution is to know the size of your cols....